# Can a guy wear a woman's helmet safely?

Tags: safety, helmets

I'm a guy and since I started wearing a helmet for mostly Trail Riding and occasionally for commuting, I noticed that the helmet looks really large on my head. My doctor later confirmed with a tape that my head is slightly smaller than average, and this explains why my helmet looks weird on me. I would like to wear a smaller helmet.

I have a couple of questions in this regard:

1. Are Women's helmets any smaller than men's?
2. If they are, would it be **safe** for me to wear one (assuming I can find a color I like!) ?
3. Are there in fact helmets for teenagers that might be useful in my situation?

I am slightly below average height and about 145 lbs.

Comment: Good quality helmets are offered in multiple sizes, or, at the very least, have ample facilities to adjust the fit.  The smaller sizes are apt to be sold as "women's" helmets, but, aside from the floral decals, they're the same as men's helmets.

Comment: Helmets for women typically have the same shape and size as men, but come in different colors. The main design difference is women helmets accommodate smaller egos better. However once your mates find you wearing a womans helmet, the problem of a mans ego not fitting into a  womans helmet usually resolves itself.

Comment: To be clear, the issue is not one of fit - the helmets that look big on me still fit fine.

Comment: @RyanShripat if a smaller helmet fits, it's likely the larger one doesn't fit as well as it could/should.

Comment: Interesting point, @Trengot...

Comment: Nobody has answered #1 yet. I think its an interesting point since the thickness of the material should roughly be the same and the adjustment mostly happens at the back of the head. So I doubt that women’s helmets (or any small helmets) are noticeable smaller (i.e. thinner, not putting as much material on your head).

Comment: Ah, interesting - we do not have men's and women's helmets in France - there is only one stand for helmets (at least in the two largest sports stores)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

"Women's" helmet is a pure marketing feature. All helmets have to pass the same safety standards and if it fits wear it.

Most helmet models come in at least 2 or 3 sizes. You should be able to find a helmet in the size that fits your head diameter. All the major manufacturers make helmets for every head size from 2 year olds to XL for adults. Every helmet should
have the head size range listed somewhere on the box.

Comment: Also worth considering the shape. Different brands may vary, so try a few to see if they fit your head better.

Comment: @vclaw - Yep, different brands, or different lines within a brand, will likely have different fits.  You just have to try on several and find what you like.

Comment: I agree on that you better try them, diferent shapes can render a helmet unwearable. My oblong head would never fit a round helmet (BMX Style) because they would squish my head front-to-back while nothing would stop 'em from wiggling side to side. Test several to get the best fit!

Answer (score 2):

Many helmets are offered in various sizes.
Often the cheaper helmets will only come in one size.
This is an example of a helmet offered in 3 sizes [Bell Lumen](http://www.bellhelmets.com/cycling/helmets/pavement/lumen).
Many of the helmets also offers an adjustable band.
A mountain bike helmet should work fine for commuting.

Answer (score 1):

Women's helmets do not usually have women specific features. They may come in more "girly" colors or some may accommodate ponytails or other hairstyles (I don't know that this exists) but there is nothing special about a women's helmet that would make it any less protective for a man. Just make sure it has a good fit and you'll be safe.

Comment: Long hair worn in a tail is not just for women. At one time I was asked about long hair and working with machines and all long haired people at work were male.

Comment: That's a good point! Men can have long hair too, duh